# Creation of BitmapSource objects no longer possible in WinRT apps?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

BitmapSource does not have the Create method in the .NET API for Windows Store apps. I assume dynamically creating images is no longer possible (if so, why?). Or does anyone know how to create images programmatically in a Windows Store app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ and the Imaging extensions.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Nice toolkit. But does it allow creation of BitmapSource? What I found out thanks to the toolkis is that WriteableBitmap allows creation. And that makes sense.

Comment: BitmapImage is probably what you are looking for. Both BitmapImage and WriteableBitmap derive from BitmapSource which is more like an abstract base class (not sure why it is not marked abstract in WinRT - probably some limitation of the language projection infrastructure).

Answer (score 0):

WriteableBitmap is the answer. It has a constructor that takes with and height and allows writing to it and updating.